# If $F\in\mathcal D \implies \left\lvert \frac{F^n(0)}{n} - F(0)\right\rvert\le\frac{n-1}{n}\, ,\forall \,n\in\mathbb N$

Tags: analysis, inequality, dynamical-systems, rotations

> Let $F\in\mathcal D$, $\phi=F-id$, show that $\left\lvert \cfrac{F^n(0)}{n} - F(0)\right\rvert\le\cfrac{n-1}{n} ,\forall\, n\in\mathbb N$

Note: We define $\mathcal D$ as the set of increasing homomorphisms (under $\mathbb R$) s.t $F=\phi +id$, where $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous $1-$periodic function.
Note: $f^n:=f\circ f\circ\dots\circ f,$ $n$ times.

---

I showed that if $\rho(F) :=\lim_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{F^n(0)}{n}$, then
$$\min\{F^n(x)-x:x\in\mathbb R\}\le n\rho(F)\le \max\{F^n(x)-x:x\in\mathbb R\}$$
but i'm note sure if that's useful here, any hints?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $x \in [0,1]$, we see that :
$$\phi(x)+x- \phi(0)= F(x)-F(0) \ge 0$$
so $\phi(x) -\phi(0) \ge -1 \quad \forall x \in [0,1]$, but we have in addition that $\phi$ is 1-periodic, hence $$\phi(x)-\phi(0) \ge -1 \quad \forall x$$
Similarly, for all $x \in [-1,0]$, we can imply a similar result, then :
$$\phi(x) -\phi(0 ) \le 1 \quad \forall x$$
In other words, $$ | \phi(x) -\phi(0)| \le 1$$ for all $x$.

So for all $n$ we have:

$$| F^{n+1}(0)-(n+1)F(0)| \le | F^{n}(0)- nF(0)| +| \phi( F^{n}(0))-\underbrace{F(0)}_{= \phi(0)}| \le | F^{n}(0)- nF(0)| +1$$

Hence forth the conclusion.

Comment: Oh i see... it was easier than I thought!
Appreciated sir Nguyen.

Comment: No problem, it is surely easier than you thought.